# Changing Image Colour

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, colors, nullpointerexception

I am currently trying to change the colour of an imageview. I am trying to do this from a fragment, and it works fine until I switch activities. When I return to the fragment that I use to change the colour of the image I get this error,

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.getColor(int)' on a null object reference
```

I use the following code to change the colour of my image,

```
imgUpvote.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.lGrey));
```

Anyone know a fix? This error only occurs when I switch activities, thanks for any answers.

EDIT:here is where code is located,

```
firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<postsGetInfo, postsGetInfoViewHolder>(postsGetInfo.class, R.layout.posts_layout,postsGetInfoViewHolder.class,postRef) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(final postsGetInfoViewHolder viewHolder, postsGetInfo model, int position) {
                    final String postKey = getRef(position).getKey();
                    UpdateTheDisplayVotes(postKey); //Displays the votes at the start of creation
                    postRef.removeEventListener(VoteListener);

                    defaultVote = VotesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(postKey)) {
                                VotesRef.child(postKey).child(current_user_id).child("votes").setValue("none");
                            }
                            String voteStatus = dataSnapshot.child(postKey).child(current_user_id).child("votes").getValue().toString();
                           if (voteStatus.equals("upvoted")){
                                ImageView btnUpvote = viewHolder.myView.findViewById(R.id.imgUpvote);
                                ImageView btnDownvote = viewHolder.myView.findViewById(R.id.imgDownvote);
                               btnUpvote.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.lBlue));
                                btnDownvote.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.lGrey));
                            }if (voteStatus.equals("downvoted")){
                                ImageView btnUpvote = viewHolder.myView.findViewById(R.id.imgUpvote);
                                ImageView btnDownvote = viewHolder.myView.findViewById(R.id.imgDownvote);
                                btnUpvote.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.lGrey));
                                btnDownvote.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.Black));
                            }if (voteStatus.equals("none")){
                                ImageView btnUpvote = viewHolder.myView.findViewById(R.id.imgUpvote);
                                ImageView btnDownvote = viewHolder.myView.findViewById(R.id.imgDownvote);
                                btnUpvote.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.lGrey));
                                btnDownvote.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.lGrey));
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Use **[getActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#getActivity%28%29)**

Comment: `getActivity()` does the same thing

Comment: share your code where you are using `imgUpvote.setColorFilter()`

Comment: will do, gimme a sec

Comment: Updated the post, the colour of the upvote/downvote will happen at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this get `Context` like this in your `fragment`

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


    public BlankFragment() {

    }

    Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }

}
```

than use like this

```
kimgUpvote.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.lGrey));
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for the brilliant answer

Comment: @BenHenderson happy to help you