# Can getContext() be null in this flow?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

If I have an `onClickListener` that is called when user clicks on a button and that listener does a callback to a method of the containing fragment which does `getContext()`.
Is there a case that the `getContext()` in this sequence could return `null`?
I am trying to understanding if doing `Context c = getContext(); if(c == null) return;` makes sense in this *specific* case/flow or is a useless defensive check

**Update for the referred links in the comments:**
I understand that when we access the context via a callback it can be null e.g. when handling a network request.
But a callback that is called when the user did an interaction with a UI element as in the case I describe is there a situation that can be `null`.
Flow is:

1. User clicks a button
2. Action listener is called and calls another callback
3. The callback listener inside the containing fragment does `getContext()`

Can this flow ever end up with `getContext()` returning `null`?

Comment: see link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987649/why-getcontext-in-fragment-sometimes-returns-null

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50329518/7666442

Comment: @nyulan: Very useful but the flow I describe is very specific and not if in general it can ever be `null`

Comment: @nyulan: I updated post

Comment: @NileshRathod: I updated post

Comment: are you inside a fragment or an activity? if fragment then call using getActivity() and if activity then call using (Activity Name).this or this or getContext().